# Drill Through/ Drill Linking/ Drill Down using Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: reporting, pentaho, drilldown, pentaho-report-designer, drillthrough

I'm using **Pentaho Report Designer** Version: **8.0.0.0-28**.
I have one summary report (1) and one detailed report (2).
Let's say I have this scenario:

I have these columns in

- (1): *Employees*, *Total hours*
- (2): *Employees*, *Day*, *Total hours per day*

I would like to make a link between (1) and (2) so if I click on **Total hours** for the employee 'John' from (1), it leads me to (2), showing **Day** and the **Total of hours per day** only for 'John'.
I wonder if it is possible to do that using the DRILLDOWN function, if yes, can you suggest me what to put in the parameters?

Also, is this possible if I publish both reports on the User Console?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, using **URL**:

-Right click on **Total Hours**

-Click on **Hyperlink**

-Put the link of the detailed report as Path

-Choose **Employee** as parameter value. (I already had a parameter that filters the report based on the name of the employee)

-Then **publish** the report in order to make it function in the User Console.